# Show the level sets are connected

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, connectedness

I am trying to prove the level sets of the function
$$
F(x,y) = 2x+2y+\sin(x)+\sin(y)
$$
are connected. I noticed that $\|\nabla F(x,y)\|>0$ for every point of the plane and that $F$ is the sum of a linear function with a $2\pi-$periodic one. Because of the never-vanishing gradient property, all the level sets should be diffeomorphic, and it should hence be enough to prove $F^{-1}(0)$ is connected.

For other similar problems, I usually show that I can express the set as the image through a homomorphism of the real line or a connected set. I can not do this here, however.

I considered using "global implicit function theorems" to glue together the local versions, but I do not seem to make this approach work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Nonvanishing of the gradient is *not* sufficient for all level sets to be diffeomorphic; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914334/conditions-for-level-sets-to-be-diffeomorphic-to-each-other/3916416#3916416).

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to characterise $F^{-1}(0)$. I suggest we write
$$ F(x, y) = f(x) + f(y),$$
where
$$ f(t) := 2t + \sin t.$$

Notice that $f$ is (i) one-to-one and (ii) odd.

This implies that
$$ F^{-1}(0) = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x = -y \},$$
which is clearly connected.

---

And then, what about the other level sets? A Google search about your idea took me to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914334/conditions-for-level-sets-to-be-diffeomorphic-to-each-other#:%7E:text=One%20sufficient%20condition%20to%20guarantee,as%20%7Cx%7C%E2%86%92%E2%88%9E). However, I think we can parametrise the level sets explicitly.

Since $f$ is a continuous bijective function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, it has an inverse $f^{-1}$ which is also a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

The level set $F^{-1}(c)$ is given by
$$ \{ (f^{-1}(t), f^{-1}(c - t)) : t \in \mathbb R \}.$$

From this representation, hopefully you can see that $F^{-1}(c)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, via the maps:

- $\mathbb R \to F^{-1}(c)$, $t \mapsto (f^{-1}(t), f^{-1}(c - t))$
- $F^{-1}(c) \to \mathbb R$, $(x, y) \mapsto f(x)$.

And of course, $\mathbb R$ is connected.

(In fact, this parameterisation is not just a homeomorphism but also a diffeomorphism, since $f^{-1}$ is smooth by virtue of $f$ having a strictly positive derivative everywhere. But that's not relevant for proving that the level sets are connected.)

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks. How would you proceed in case instead of $2y$ there were $y$ ? The gradient would still be never vanishing, but the function in $y$ is not one-to-one anymore

Comment: @Dadeslam If you replace $2x$ with $x$ and $2y$ with $y$, then the gradient does vanish, right? The gradient vanishes when $(x, y) = ((2m + 1)\pi, (2n + 1)\pi)$ where $m, n \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: By the way, if you have questions about variations of this setup, it might be a good idea to ask another question on this site.

Comment: Sure, I was thinking only to do the change for the $y$. But you are right, it would be better to ask a separate one