# Is a level set of a real valued function f(x,y,z) with non-vanishing gradient and partials that depend only on z connected?

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

I have a smooth function $f : P \rightarrow R$, where $P$ is the positive orthant of $R^3$. I know that $\partial f / \partial x,\; \partial f / \partial y$ are both $> 0$  everywhere on $P$ and that $\partial f / \partial z < 0$, also everywhere on $P$. Finally, I know that all three partials are functions only of $z$.

**Question**: If $c$ is a regular value of $f$ is $M \equiv f^{-1} (c)$ a connected submanifold?

I know in general that questions about the connectedness of level sets can be difficult to answer and there is no one way of attacking them. For example, I've seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804132/show-the-level-sets-are-connected) discussion, which is quite specific as to the form of the function. I've also seen [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914334/conditions-for-level-sets-to-be-diffeomorphic-to-each-other/3916416#3916416), but it requires that we know the level sets are compact. My avenues of attack so far have been first, to see if I can prove $M$ is path connected and second, to try and use the implicit function theorem to show that $M$ is locally a graph and then extend it using what I know of $\nabla f$. Neither approach has proved fruitful.

I don't know the answer to my question. I was just hoping, given the specialized properties of $f$, that there is a specific way to attack it.

**Update**: In response to Paul Frost's comment, the origin of this question lies in what is known as public economics. The functions $f$ are *marginal rate of substitution* functions. Specifically, we are given a family of utility functions $U^i(X,Y_1,\ldots,Y_k) : P^{k+1} \rightarrow P, 1 \leq i \leq n$ (here $P^k$ indicates the strictly positive orthant of $R^k$). We assume that for all $i$ the partial derivatives $U^i_X > 0,\;U^i_{XX} < 0,\; U^i_{Y_j} > 0,\;U^i_{Y_j Y_j} < 0,\; 1 \leq j \leq k$. For each $i$ the MRS of good $X$ for good $Y_j$ is defined as $f^i_j = U^i_{Y_j} / U^i_X$. Then the functions $\partial f^i_j /\partial X > 0,\; \partial f^i_j / \partial Y_j < 0, 1 \leq i \leq n, \; 1 \leq j \leq k$.

This is just a quick summary of what's involved, the precise question is a bit more complicated, but hopefully the above will suffice to answer the question. For an example of functions satisfying the above you can take: $$U^i(X,Y_1,\ldots,Y_k) = c^i X^\alpha Y^{\beta^i_1}_1 \cdot \cdot \cdot Y^{\beta^i_k}_k$$ where $\alpha$ and the $\beta^i_j$ terms are some positive constants.

**Extending the Example**: With the above we get the following MRS functions $$f^i_j(X,Y_1,\ldots,Y_k) = \frac{\beta^i_j X}{\alpha Y_j},$$ so that
$$\frac {\partial f^i_j}{ \partial X} = \frac {\beta^i_j}{\alpha Y_j}.$$ Also $$\frac {\partial f^i_j}{\partial Y_j} = -f^i_j \frac{1}{Y_j}$$ and $$\frac {\partial f^i_j}{\partial Y_s} = 0$$ for $s \neq j$. The $r$th row of my matrix (don't know how to use mathjax easily for matrices) is $$\frac{\partial f^1_r}{\partial X} \cdots \frac{\partial f^n_r}{\partial X},\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f^i_r}{\partial Y_1} \cdots \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f^i_r}{\partial Y_k}.$$ Finally, the model dictates that we must have $\sum_{i=1}^n f^i_r = 1,\; 1 \leq r \leq k$, which gives the matrix I asked about (I think). I apologize for not including this in the question but I didn't think I would be asked for an example (glad I was, however). I also apologize for mischaracterizing the behavior of $f$ as I see now that there is a sum involved in some entries and also that some entries vanish, so that they are not $ < 0$. Paul Frost has caught this, I'm assuming that there is no function $f$ that strictly satisfies the behavior stated in my question.

**Update**: I believe the example I gave results in the level set being a hyperplane (hence convex so trivially connected). I need to do more work on this, clearly. My thanks to Paul Frost for his insightful comments.

Comment: What is the origin of your question? Do you have an example for such a function $f$?

Comment: Then you do not get examples satisying your requirements. Consider a function $f(x,y,z) = cx^\alpha y^\beta z^\gamma$. You get $\partial f/\partial z =  cx^{\alpha} y^\beta z^{\gamma-1}$ which only depends on $z$, thus you must have $\alpha = \beta = 0$ or $c = 0$ (which is uninteresting). Hence $f(x,y,z) = cz^\gamma$ and  $\partial f/\partial x =  \partial f/\partial y = 0$.

Comment: I may have explained myself incorrectly. I'll edit my response in the answer to extend the example (of course I could be wrong).

Comment: So $P$ is the positive real line? And what are $U^i_r , U^i_{rr}, U^i_{Y_j}, U^i_X$? Partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes, and those are partial derivatives, I tried to make the notation more compact and may have confused things, I'll edit my answer further.

Comment: For matrices see https://www.math-linux.com/latex/faq/latex-faq/article/how-to-write-matrices-in-latex-matrix-pmatrix-bmatrix-vmatrix-vmatrix. I think you should explain the role of this matrix. And the relation of your initial question to your eaxmple is a bit unclear.

Comment: I will take your advice, but my feeling (could be wrong) is that MSE would probably rather have me start a whole new question (with a link back to this one) since my initial question post would get rather lengthy. I need to be more careful about how I present the new version, so it will take a bit of time, but I think you're right. Thanks.